# Take back to login page after successfully reset his/her password in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to redirect to login page whenever a user successfully reset his/her password in laravel 5.4.

Currently it redirects to dashboard page after successfully reset.
I looked around all stuff all are saying to place
protected $redirectTo = '/home'; in protected $redirectTo = '/';
But it does not give me any solution.

Comment: `protected $redirectTo='/login'`

Comment: Not work, It take me to home page instead of login page.

Comment: if you are trying reset password after login it will take you to homepage

Comment: try to unset or flush your session redirect it to login

Comment: I am not using like that. This is not a process of reseting password of a user. @NikhilRadadiya

Comment: @Saroj try clearing your cache and config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Laravel authenticates the user after they reset their password. So it's impossible to redirect to the login page since only guest users can view the login page. Even if you set the `$redirectTo` to `/login`, the guest middleware would redirect the user back to `/home` since the user is authenticated.

If you need to prevent the user from being automatically logged in on resetting password and redirect them to the login page, you need to follow these steps.

Do the following changes in `ResetPasswordController` located at `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`.

Change the redirect path to your login page.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/login';
```

Override the `resetPassword` method to prevent user being logged in. Add this to the controller.

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => bcrypt($password),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();
}
```

Add this on top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

---

The original method in `ResetsPasswords` trait looks like this.

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => bcrypt($password),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

**Edit** : To send a custom response on redirection you can override `sendResetResponse` in your controller and add any custom session/flash messages. By default laravel sets its own response on successful password reset.

```
protected function sendResetResponse($response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                        ->with('status', trans($response));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeesh It worked perfectly. In addition you should mention that we need to add 
use Auth;  And 
use Illuminate\Support\Str; in top of the code.

Comment: 1 more question on this, I want to show some message to the user after take back to login page. How Can I achive this.

Comment: @Saroj Edited the answer and added the `use` and info on how to add custom message.

Comment: You are a champion hurdler. :)

Comment: @Sandeesh Getting error message `Illegal offset type` for `return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));`. Any suggestion?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When password successfully reset. It should auto set the session/cookie as logged on user. Try to unset the session/cookie and middleware will detect that no login is happening and you should redirected to /login page after successfully reset password.

Answer (score 0):

before

```
$user->forceFill(...)->save();
```

after

```
$user->fresh();

Auth::guard('web')->login($user, $user->remember_token == NULL);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.