# Laravel authorization

Tags: laravel

How after password recovery (ResetPassword), to make sure that the user does not automatically log in and redirect to the main page, but simply display a message like "Your password was changed successfully", etc. in Laravel?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are more than welcome to adjust the methods the `ResetController` uses which includes the functionality of logging in the user after resetting their password and the response that you return

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44235671/4575350